# Sum Function not working in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sum a column of a table based on another sum of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617958/sum-a-column-of-a-table-based-on-another-sum-of-a-table)

I sum up a column from an already summed column in a sub-select in sql but it gives me the same value as the already summed column. The TotalAmount is supposed to add up to the InvoiceTotal but it just copies the same value. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to go about this?

```
declare @ReportLines table 
    (RebateInvoiceID int, 
     RebateSetupID int ,
     ShortItemNo float primary key(RebateInvoiceID,RebateSetupID,ShortItemNo),
     TotalAmount float,
     InvoiceTotal float,
     TotalQuantity int )
insert @ReportLines
select
  Total.RebateInvoiceID
, Total.ID
, Total.ShortItemNo
, Total.TotalAmount
, sum(Total.TotalAmount) as InvoiceTotal
, Total.TotalQuantity
from
(
select 
i.RebateInvoiceID
,coalesce(rs.WholesalerRebateSetupID,r.RebateSetupID) as ID
,bl.ShortItemNo
, sum(round(r.Amount,2)) as TotalAmount
, sum(r.Quantity) TotalQuantity
from
  @Invoices i
  join RebateInvoices ri (nolock) on 
    ri.RebateInvoiceID=i.RebateInvoiceID
  inner loop join Rebates r (nolock) on
    r.RebateInvoiceID=i.RebateInvoiceID       
  join RebateSetup rs (nolock) on
    rs.RebateSetupID=r.RebateSetupID
  join BidLines bl (nolock) on 
    r.BidLineGuid=bl.BidLineGuid
  join @Products p on
    p.ShortItemNo=bl.ShortItemNo
  left join ChargebackDetailHistory cd (nolock) on 
    r.DocumentBranchPlant = cd.DocumentBranchPlant
    and r.DocumentNumber = cd.DocumentNumber
    and r.DocumentType = cd.DocumentType
    and r.LineNumber = cd.LineNumber
  left join EDI.dbo.JDE_SaleDetail sd (nolock) on 
    r.DocumentBranchPlant = sd.BranchPlant
    and r.DocumentNumber = sd.OrderNumber
    and r.DocumentType = sd.OrderType
    and r.LineNumber = sd.LineNumber
where 
    cd.InvoiceDate between @BeginDate and @EndDate
    or sd.InvoiceDate between @BeginDate and @EndDate
group by
  i.RebateInvoiceID
, coalesce(rs.WholesalerRebateSetupID,r.RebateSetupID)
, bl.ShortItemNo
) Total

group by 
total.rebateinvoiceid,
total.ID,
total.shortitemno,
total.totalamount,
total.totalquantity
```

Comment: If you are not getting answers to your first question, then consider editing it to be clearer rather than posting the exact same question

Comment: @user...try removing total.totalamount from the group by at the end of your query and from the select....see what happens

Answer (score 6):

Do not do grouping on the same field that you trying to do SUM on.

Comment: thats exactly what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 3):

It's because you group by `TotalAmount` and `TotalQuantity`. It makes no sense to group by these values. And since the three remaining group fields are the same as in the sub-select you will get the same rows. You would have to group by less fields in order to unify several rows of the sub-select into one row of the outer select to get sums of the sums.

But is seems to me that this outer select makes no sense at all, why not just use the inner select alone?